# Excel VBA - getting Permission Denied errors when trying to use File System Object to move files

Tags: excel, vba

When using a FileSystemObject to move a list of files, I will on occasion get Permission Denied errors. This appears to be a timing issue with the code processing too quickly after closing a file. Any ideas and/or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following block of Do While code which waits a second and then tries again. I've never seen more than one retry needed to accomplish the move. I omitted most of the variable definitions, etc for brevity.

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
On Error Resume Next
Do
    Err.Clear
    Call fso.MoveFile(strTemporaryFileName, strFileName)
    ' Permission denied.
    If Err.Number = 70 Then
        lngRetries = lngRetries + 1
        ' Wait approximately 1 second and try again - Have never known it to take more than one retry.
        Call Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Debug.Print "Retrying file move - Error 70, Permission Denied found at " & Now & " " & fso.GetFileName(strFileName)
    End If
    If lngRetries > 5 Then
        Call MsgBox("File cannot be created for " & fso.GetFileName(strFileName), vbOKOnly Or vbCritical, "Excel Error")
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop While Err.Number = 70
Set fso = Nothing
```